# How can I group table data?

Tags: mysql

I have a following table:

```
mysql> select * from playground order by locatedAt;
+------------+---------------------+--------------+
| macAddress | locatedAt           | status       |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:20:27 | connected    |
| device2    | 2014-08-11 01:20:27 | connected    |
| device2    | 2014-08-11 01:30:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:30:27 | connected    |
| device2    | 2014-08-11 01:40:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:40:27 | disconnected |
| device2    | 2014-08-11 01:49:27 | connected    |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:49:27 | connected    |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:50:27 | disconnected |
| device2    | 2014-08-11 01:53:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:55:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 02:05:27 | disconnected |
| device2    | 2014-08-11 02:10:27 | disconnected |
| device2    | 2014-08-11 02:15:27 | disconnected |
```

I need the data to be summarized in such a way that it should be grouped by hour of the day and by the status of the device. Expected output:

```
hour | connected | disconnected
01   |  5        | 6
02   |  0        | 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried the "COUNT()" statement, and/or "GROUP BY"?

Answer (score 2):

Do just that. Get the hour of the locatedAt column with the function HOUR sum up the status values and group by the DATE part and the HOUR part of the locatedAt column:

```
SELECT
    HOUR(locatedAt) hour,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='connected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) connected,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='disconnected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) disconnected
FROM
    playground
GROUP BY 
    DATE(locatedAt), HOUR(locatedAt);
```

You can simplify the expression as Strawberry mentioned:

```
SELECT
    HOUR(locatedAt) hour,  
    SUM(status='connected') connected,
    SUM(status='disconnected') disconnected
FROM
    playground
GROUP BY 
    DATE(locatedAt), HOUR(locatedAt);
```

because in MySQL `TRUE` is implemented as 1 and `FALSE` as 0, see [Logical Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html):

> In SQL, all logical operators evaluate to TRUE, FALSE, or NULL
>   (UNKNOWN). In MySQL, these are implemented as 1 (TRUE), 0 (FALSE), and
>   NULL.

Working in a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17f26/3)

Comment: **Side question** Does that work on MySQL? Because it seems that it has a reduced instruction set compared to standard SQL...

Comment: Nice! I've never seen the `CASE WHEN` statement before in MySQL but I'm going to use it for sure now. Cheers!

Comment: @Rems What is 'standard sql'?

Comment: @Strawberry Well, what I call 'standard SQL' is just its official specification. But MySQL, as close as it gets to it, does not implements every keywords, as for instance some `JOIN` statements. Though, these statements are available in MSSQL. I've been blocked by that a few month ago while I was writing a very specific request on MySQL. I had to go for a workaround because I couldn't join tables the way I wanted, a way which was possible in MSSQL and not in MySQL.

Comment: @Strawberry BTW, I'm not a SQL specialist so I may be mistaking. Maybe MySQL gets closer to the official spec than MSSQL. Sure thing is that they do not implement the same keywords.

Comment: All dialects of SQL deviate from 'the ANSI standard', I don't think MySQL is particularly extreme (or deficient) in this respect

Comment: In MySQL this can be reduced to SUM(status='connected')